# Dynamically Create Controls Based On Database field Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a database table that looks like so:

| fieldid | form_id | control_type | parentid | order_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | panel | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | textbox | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | checkbox | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | panel | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | checkbox | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | textbox | 4 | 1 |

There are other fields that I want to attach to this table but I want to dynamically create controls within the associated panel by using  recursion.

I call the load_form with two parameters from the page_load event
my page has one panel in it called PnlMain and this panel is where I want the dynamically loaded controls placed within.

can anyone help me out with how to load only the controls that are associated with the "panels" with the fieldid that's equal to the associated controls parentid

Here is my code behind.

```
Sub load_form(c As Control, Optional parent_id As Integer = 0)
    i = i + 1
    Dim frmid As Integer
    If Request("formid") Is Nothing Then
        frmid = 1
    Else
        frmid = Request("formid")
    End If


    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim sql As String = ""
    If parent_id = 0 Then
        sql = "SELECT * from form_fields where form_id=" & frmid & " order by parentid, order_number"
        dt = GetData(sql)
    Else
        sql = "SELECT * from form_fields where form_id=" & frmid & " and parentid=" & parent_id & "  order by parentid, order_number"
        dt = GetData(sql)
    End If

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            ' MsgBox(sql)
            Dim p As New Panel()
            If row(2).ToString.Trim(" ") = "panel" Then
                '  MsgBox(dt.Rows(0)(0))
                Dim pnl As New Panel()
                pnl.ID = "pnl" & row(0)
                pnl.GroupingText = row(9)
                p = pnl
                load_form(p, row(0))
            End If
            If row(2).ToString.Trim() = "textbox" Then
                Dim t As New TextBox With {
                    .CssClass = "form-control"}
                t.Attributes.Add("showto", "true")
                t.Attributes.Add("dbdata", "true")
                t.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter O2 Level...")
                t.ID = "Txt" & i
                p.Controls.Add(t)
            End If
            If row(2).ToString.Trim() = "checkbox" Then
                Dim cb As New CheckBox With {
                    .CssClass = "cb form-control"}
                cb.Attributes.Add("showto", "All")
                cb.Attributes.Add("dbdata", "true")
                cb.Attributes.Add("title", row("title").ToString.Trim())
                cb.Attributes.Add("altValue", row("altvalue").ToString.Trim())
                cb.Text = row(7).ToString.Trim()
                cb.ID = "cb" & i
                p.Controls.Add(cb)
            End If
            c.Controls.Add(p)
   
        Next
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do this, but the problem then is you can't wire up server side events for each of the controls (code behind). The code behind events require the designer and event code is setup/resolved  at compile time - not run time. JavaScript code for the events and web method calls into the page I suppose could work - but that's going to get messy. If you looking to just display the controls (and perhaps have code fill out values - then fine - but keep in mind that adding events to such controls will be difficult. So for display, and even curd editor you are ok but events will be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I figured it out. The form is just collecting the values and all the values are being sent to the database. There's no event wire-up  for any of the dynamic controls.